# How to access Azure AD using Azure Function App in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Can I access Azure AD informations using Azure Functions? I'd like to send email using SendGrid and grab the email from the AD. Where do I start in doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. The main step is requesting an access token.Then use this access token to [call microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#5-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph) to grab the email from the AD.

You can use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token. Here is the code for your reference.

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'login.microsoftonline.com';

var tenant = '{your_tenant_name}';
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var resource = 'https://graph.microsoft.com'; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.

var applicationId = '{your_application_id}';
var clientSecret = '{your_client_secret}';
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks! I followed the steps 1-5 on your [link to call microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service). Used it with postman first. Then in Azure, I used request module for POST to have the token (had to use x-www-form-urlencoded). Then used https module for GET to have the AD details fo the user.